# String Matching Function Will Not Work Properly

Tags: java, string, arraylist, hashtable, contains

I have a function that is supposed to scan a string and return true if the string contains a curse word and false otherwise.

```
public static boolean isBad(String s) {
    //cussWords is a previously defined arraylist containing all possible spellings of all swear words (Loaded from a utf8 encoded file if that matters)
    s = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "").toLowerCase();
    String[] arr = s.split(" ");
    for (String str : arr) { //Break sentence into words and check each word
        str = str.trim();
        if (cussWords.contains(str)){ //Check if it is bad using ArrayList.contains function
            System.out.printf("\"%s\" contains a bad word.\n",s);
            return true;
        }
        if (badWords[hash(str)] != null) { //Check if it is bad using hash table

            System.out.printf("'%s' contains bad word: %s|%s\n", s, badWords[hash(str)], str);
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("'%s' does not contain any bad words.\n", s);
    return false;
}
```

When the inputs are hard-coded

```
System.out.println(cussWords.contains(*swear word*));
```

or

```
System.out.println(isBad(*sentence with swear word*));
```

the outputs are correct, but when running on the server with dynamic inputs the function always returns false. I have spent hours testing each component to this function in isolation and each part works on its own, but when put together they do not. I do not know if possibly the code is corrupted or maybe I'm just missing something.

I call the function here

```
        if (isCensored) {
        while (Dictionary.isBad(response)) {
            response = db.fetchResponse(db.all.get(r.nextInt(db.all.size()))); //db.all is an arraylist containing all possible responses stored in the database (It's a chat bot)
        }
    }
```

Here is the gist of the problem (in my code it isn't censored)

```
System.out.println(wordSet.contains("f***")); //Returns true

    for (String str : arr) {
        str = str.trim();
        System.out.println(str.equals("f***")); //Returns true
        if (wordSet.contains(str)){ //Returns false
            System.out.printf("\"%s\" contains a bad word.\n",s);
            return true;
        }
  }
```

Comment: are you sure cusswords and badwords have some data in them on server? mind printing out their size() in logs or STDOUT?

Comment: You're not showing how `isBad()` is called for "dynamic input". And that is important, as you say that `isBad()` works when called from test.

Comment: The problem is in how you're reading dynamic inputs then.

Comment: I have printed the value of str inside the loop and I have verified that each word is being properly passed through the loop.

Comment: Yes, but have you verified you have correctly loaded your cussWords on the server.    If it is empty you will get no matches

Comment: What you're trying to do here is implement poor mans Set - a collection that is supposed to be fast when checking whether an element is contained by it or not. De facto https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html works in similiar way as you're trying to do it. Maybe use builtin class instead of arraylist approach?

Comment: Yes, I have verified that both cussWords and badwords have the data they are supposed to have on the server.

Comment: I just implemented it with a hashset and I'm having the same result. For some reason, when inside the for loop, none of the comparisons seem to work properly. But I have verified that it's not a problem loading the words because before the loop I hard coded set.contains("f***");, which it says is true. Then in the loop I compare str to "f***", which is also true. Yet it says set.contains(str) is false.

Comment: Looking at the code you put into the question, it is indeed surprising that this does not work as intended. You should probably use the debugger to step through the code. It will quickly reveal what goes wrong here.

Comment: Like Alex said, debugger should solve this quickly. But since it only fails on the server the two obvious possibilities are: 1) The code running on the server isn't the same. Clean & redeploy everything. Make sure the timestamp of the files on the server changes, Make changes to the printf's and see the change take effect. 2) Something is different about the way isBad is called on the server. You didn't show us that code? Also wouldn't hurt to post the output.